# How to make eclipse pick customized source dir in maven environment?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, customization, directory-structure

### Here is my project in window explorer:

[image]

### Here is when I import it as `Existing Maven Project`:

[image]

### Here is the build path:

[image]

You can see that the source directory is not picked by maven/eclipse by default; maven by default picks the following directory by default:

`src/main/java` 
`src/main/resources` 
`src/test/java`

I was wondering if there is a way to configure maven(m2e plugin)/eclipse to pick `src/main-java-templates` source directory aswell automatically on import instead of manually adding it to build path?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your pom's build section:

```
<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java-templates</sourceDirectory>
```

Comment: If I add this then it would remove `src/main/java` source dir from the source build path!

Comment: Add an entry for src/main/java

Comment: I had to use [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to set multiple source directories. Your solution only sets a single source directory in eclipse; it complains about having multiple `<sourceDirectory>` elements!!!